# Remesh for post base concrete that will have lateral forces

Tags: concrete, post, rebar

Would using rolled up remesh be suitable for reinforcing the concrete in the below scenario?

I'm planning to install some post bases in some concrete which will serve as the bottom of a 16-ft long, 3-ft-wide, rope ladder which ascends 11 vertical feet. This ladder will also have ~6ft side netting for safety reasons which will attach to the top of the posts.

The plan is to do a bell pier shape with Maximizer concrete and be about 12 inches wide at top and 18 at bottom and 3ft deep.  There will be Simpson 4x6 anchors installed on top and the posts attached to those.

There will be lateral working load forces from multiple people climbing the rope ladder at once, so I'm wondering if remesh is sufficient for this or if I should do rebar or some different approach.  I've also considered whether something additional will be needed to help handle the forces.

EDIT2: additional details added

Most of the force will be at the base of the post as shear force since that's where the ladder net connects, but there will be some amount of bend force from people putting their hands on the vertical side netting. This is Simpson model PBS46 and per footnote 8 on page 2 of https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/nzzsptbebm/C-C-2021-p74-75.pdf it says 1,165 lb of force per post in that manner, so if across 2 posts and relatively evenly distributed it would be even higher.

EDIT: rough diagram added

[image]

Comment: A sketch would really help.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate added - thanks

Comment: Ground conditions that the holes/posts are put into can be important.  3 feet not that deep really for sideways forces, braces/guy wires might be needed.  For safety of people, having an engineer check might be the best.

Comment: +1 to engineering, unless the bother of a failure isn’t that big a deal. To the original question, I don’t think remesh would make a difference, though I might seriously consider having rebar welded on to extend the post base depth.

Comment: If your posts will only be anchored to the top of the pier, I highly doubt you'll have sufficient bending strength, unless only toddlers will be using this rope ladder.

Comment: Yeah, I think @Huesmann has hit the key item. The concrete base may last for centuries as planned, but the post attachments don't sound like they'll last a week of use by adults.

Comment: @Huesmann These will be 4x6 posts so are decently strong and most of the force will be at the base of the post as shear force since that's where the ladder net connects, but there will be some amount of bend force from people putting their hands on the vertical side netting. Does this impact your thoughts on the situation?

Comment: @FreeMan I just added additional thoughts on the forces involved in reply to Huesmann if you have any thoughts on the matter in light of those.

Comment: Simpson makes a lot of post bases. I'm not sure which one you're using. Make sure it will support the lateral loads you're expecting. "Multiple people" on a 16' foot rope ladder going up 11' implies a lot of sag in the ladder which means a lot of movement by each person compounding into much more force than just their combined weights. I'm no engineer, but that's "a lot" of force, and probably _more_ than you're thinking.

Comment: @FreeMan it's PBS46 and per footnote 6 on page 1 of https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/nzzsptbebm/C-C-2021-p74-75.pdf it says 765lbs of shear so across 2 posts if evenly distributed would be a pretty sizeable load rating - thoughts?

Comment: @FreeMan Correction - footnote 8 of p2 of that link - 1,165 lb per post

Comment: Couple of notions: the strength of the base is probably okay, except you’ve disturbed the ground in the direction of pull. If it was me, I’d have a big 2x2 block for each post, set deep (4’ is my gut, though frost lines might make that too little). You’ll want to make the acquaintance of a mini mix concrete vendor. (They mix small loads on the spot.)

Comment: The other problem is the ‘rail’ on the side net is a force multiplier (assuming the rail isn’t rigid), and the pull on the top of the post might be massive. If it was me, I’d plant substantial metal poles (deep) and skip the wood/ Simpson base.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I like the metal pole idea - I started looking but am wondering if you have any recommendations for gauge / diameter / shape / etc.?  On the extreme end I was thinking maybe an in-ground basketball hoop post but that seems overkill on the cost and strength.  I found some schedule 40 steel pipe as a possible option or maybe some strong metal fence post? Thanks

Comment: I was thinking 3” bollards, but steel questions are way outside my lane. Find a good steel supplier and ask them what they have.